# ignore sqlprojAssemblyReference.cache

Tags: .net, git, gitignore

I have a database project in my .net solution. Whenever I am building/rebuilding the solution '.sqlprojAssemblyReference.cache' file is generated in database project's obj/Debug folder.

I have in my git ignore obj directories and cache files ignored but still it is not working as expected.

```
    # Build results
    [Dd]ebug/
    [Oo]bj/

    # Visual Studio cache files
    # files ending in .cache can be ignored
    *.[Cc]ache
    # but keep track of directories ending in .cache
    !?*.[Cc]ache/
```

I am expecting this file not to appear in my changes as I added this in .gitignore as similar to packages folder for which I added a format earlier in .gitignore. In both the cases I had not made any commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior - the build process will generate this file.

The `.gitignore` file only tells Git / Visual Studio that this file/directory is not to be added to source control.

If you have already have this file in source control - e.g. it was checked in before you added the `.gitignore` file -, you may need to forcibly remove the file from git using:

```
git rm -r --cached path\to\obj
```

or see [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Yes I understand that it will be generated as its expected behavior, but could you please let me know why it is shown as my changes after adding it in gitignore. I had another file as well that stopped appearing in my changes after adding it in gitignore. I had not made any commit though.